# Why does connection to my posgreSQL server in Azure fails?

Tags: database, postgresql, azure, ssl

I've problem here, I've been trying to load data in my postgreSQL Database, by using

```
psql -h suggestedorder.postgres.database.azure.com -d remote_mydb -U dev_ext@suggestedorder -c "\copy planning.PRUEBA (CENTRO, ALMACEN, FECHA_CARGA)  from 'C:\Users\geradiaz.MODELO\Desktop\Envase\Selección_Envase\Inputs\No_Seleccionado\PRUEBA.csv' with delimiter as ','
```

Somehow after type this sentence CMD ask for a password:

[image]

But when I try to enter my password it just doesn't work, I can't type anything, so I push enter and it shows the next message ***"Unable to connect to server: FATAL: SSL connection is required. Please specify SSL options and retry."***

[image]

Do you know guys if there is any way to make it? or How can I specify SSL options without disable them in azure?

Comment: Did you read the [psql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) where the command line options are explained and which contains also the chapter __Connecting to a Database__?

Comment: Nope @Mofi, I'm on it now, and sorry I'm a little bit new on this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But when I try to enter my password it just doesn't work, I can't type anything,

You don't get any feedback as you enter your password.  You just have to take it on faith that your keyboard is working.

> so I push enter and it shows the next message "Unable to connect to server: FATAL: SSL connection is required. Please specify SSL options and retry."

Actually the **next** message you got was "password authentication failed".  I guess because you panicked when you noticed you weren't getting feedback, and so you never finished typing the password.  (Also, "Unable to connect to server" doesn't appear in your screenshot at all, just the SSL part does)

Once psql's attempt to connect over SSL failed due to the password issue, it decided to try again without SSL.  But the server rejected this attempt, leading to the 2nd error message (I don't know what caused the exact wording of that error message, it is not a wording I have seen before).  If you set PGSSLMODE=require, then it won't bother to make this 2nd attempt, leading to cleaner error output.

Comment: You were right, even though I wasn't getting feedback, it was typing in an "invisible " way, so I tried again and it worked I could load data, one quick question, Do you know if there any way to ommit  when CMD asks for the password? @jjanes

Comment: @Xkid  Use a .pgpass file, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html.  Or set the PGPASSWORD environment variable, but that may be less secure.  Or switch to  non-password based method.  Azure (haven't used it) might support something with AD or Kerberos.